# Outlook EAS with Certificate Authentication

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ssl, certificate, activesync

I use EAS (ActiveSync) with Certificate authentication. I have been able to configure this without problems on iOS and Android. However, I don't know how to configure Certificate authentication for Outlook on Windows. I have already imported the PFX file into the Windows Certificate Store. Internet Explorer is able to Access the Active-Sync directory but Outlook is still not able to connect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How do you obtain the certificate? You can check the using method with provider. Certificate for ActiveSync may be installed in AD: [Certificate Authentication for ActiveSync](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94d5e9e2-faaa-411a-859c-0769175df366/certificate-authentication-for-activesync?forum=Exch2016SD)